# Batch file does not run properly a loop in a python script

Tags: python, batch-file, visual-studio-code, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers

I have this script

```
from ib_insync import *
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
    
util.startLoop()
ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, clientId=1)


data = {'Name': ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'GOOG', 'NVDA'], 'buy_amount': [10, 10, 10, 10]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  


for i in tqdm(df.index):    
    contract = Stock(df['Name'].iloc[i],exchange='SMART',currency='USD')
    marketOrder = MarketOrder('BUY',df['buy_amount'].iloc[i])
    marketOrder.tif = 'GTC'
    marketOrder = ib.placeOrder(contract, marketOrder)
```

I am using `ib_insync` to automate my trading. And I would like it to do everything automatically. To automate I tried using a bat file to run my scripts.

First, I can run this script without any problem in VScode. It places all orders without any problem with the loop. However, when I use `bat` file or run this scrip outside VScode (double-clicking on py script on Windows Explorer) it does not place all orders, only the first order (i.e. AAPL). Meaning that the loop only works when I run it with VScode. I do not use virtual environments, hence this should not be a problem. I could not identify the reason of the problem, any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Were any exceptions visible? Did you try to "frame" your code-sections into separate exception-proof, exceptions' self-reporting code-sections to help solve the root-cause?

Comment: @user3666197 no I cannot see any exceptions. I tried using pause at the end of the bat file but the terminal closes after placing the first order. As far as I understand the terminal should not close when I use pause at the end of bat file.  I have not tried to 'frame' my code, because I do not know how to do it yet. But that's gonna be the first thing that I learn now

Comment: run the `.bat` file in a terminal you start yourself

Comment: @rioV8 ok, thank you, I tried your suggestion and now it does not close automatically. I also used the code provided by user3666197, and the reports show that everything is ok, but it still only sends the first order with .bat file. Exactly the same code works like a charm with VScode

Comment: what is the reason to use pandas a simple list with tuples is enough

Comment: @rioV8 there is no specific reason to do it. I just don't know the other way. Can pandas cause these problems?

Answer (score 1):

As commented above,

> <sub>*"@user3666197 no I cannot see any exceptions. I tried using pause at the end of the bat file but the terminal closes after placing the first order. As far as I understand the terminal should not close when I use pause at the end of bat file. I have not tried to 'frame' my code, because I do not know how to do it yet. But that's gonna be the first thing that I learn now –
> [Bogdan Titomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15542251/bogdan-titomir)
> "*</sub>

this provisional code may help trace the root-cause :

```py
###################################### "fused"-section under review
try:
       ...code...

except aKnownAndExpectedExcREASON:
       ... a handled case ...

except:
      ... a not expected, yet happened EXC ...
      print ( "EXC: this happened in ...code... Check why ... " )

finally:
      print ( "INF: going to next section " )

######################################
```

This trivial "framing" can help you view, stop and diagnose all details when & where necessary

```py
...
#______________________________________ a risky step, so fused here
try:
     util.startLoop()
     print ( "INF: ok... " )

except:
     print ( "EXC: ..." )
     # pause

finally:
     pass
#______________________________________ a risky step, so fused here
try:
     ib = IB()
     ib.connect( '127.0.0.1',
                  7497,
                  clientId = 1 )
     print ( "INF: ok... " )

except:
     print ( "EXC: ..." )
     # pause

finally:
     pass
 
data = { 'Name':       ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'GOOG', 'NVDA'],
         'buy_amount': [10, 10, 10, 10]
          }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  


for i in tqdm(df.index):    
    contract    = Stock( df['Name'].iloc[i],
                         exchange = 'SMART',
                         currency = 'USD'
                         )
    marketOrder = MarketOrder( 'BUY', df['buy_amount'].iloc[i] )
    marketOrder.tif = 'GTC'

    #__________________________________ a risky step, so fused here
    try:
          marketOrder = ib.placeOrder( contract, marketOrder )
          print ( "INF: ok... ", i )

    except:
          print ( "EXC: ..." )
          # pause
    finally:
          pass
```

---

> *Thanks, when I run your code in VScode I get this
> INF: ok... INF: ok... 100%|██████████| 4/4 [00:00<00:00, 1999.43it/s]INF: ok... 0 INF: ok... 1 INF: ok... 2 INF: ok... 3, meaning everything is ok.
>  **I can see the same results with my bat file.** – [Bogdan Titomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15542251/bogdan-titomir)*

Cool,
that means you've sent all -4- `ib.placeOrder()`-calls without problem, i.e. either or `AAPL`, `TSLA`, `GOOG`, `NVDA` calls 
--
Q.E.D.
adding pauses and launching the same in a O/S-spawned python-interpreter ( might be printing also version-details ) shall do the rest.

Comment: Thanks, when I run your code in VScode I get this INF: ok... 
INF: ok... 
100%|██████████| 4/4 [00:00<00:00, 1999.43it/s]INF: ok...  0
INF: ok...  1
INF: ok...  2
INF: ok...  3, meaning everything is ok. I can see the same results with my bat file.

Comment: Cool, that means you've sent all -4- ib.palceOrder()-calls without problem, i.e. either or AAPL, TSLA, GOOG, NVDA calls -- **Q.E.D.** adding pauses and launching the same in a O/S-spawned python-interpreter ( might be printing also version-details ) shall do the rest - G/L on this & Happy Trading ๛

Comment: I could not edit previous comment. Although my bat file report says that everything is ok, it still sends only the first order, while if I run your code with Vscode the script places all ordrs

Comment: Thanks, what does "O/S-spawned python-interpreter" mean?

Comment: It means any means of launching the code, without using the VScode --- a) a terminal with command-line b) an ipython-ecosystem c) any of REPL-available python consoles + d) using the O/S-(configured)-associated python interpreter, that gets being launched, once user double-clicks on a .py-file ( here, we need all the above said pauses to actually be programmed so as to work and halt the flow of code interpretations, otherwise no time to read exception-specific details will be provided as objected in the O/P